# Find text in IntelliJ with case sensitive Replace

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace, find

I've got a test class that has many auto-generated methods, like this:

```
public void testInitBinder() throws Exception { }

public void testGetAllMetaLabelTbls() throws Exception { }

public void testList() throws Exception { }

public void testEdit() throws Exception { }
```

I'd like to remove the word "test" in the method name, but then have the method name correctly begin in lower case. For example `testInitBinder` would become `initBinder`.

Note, this is just an example case. I'd like to know how to do this type of find/replace in other cases outside of this specific case. (Telling me how to auto-generate without the prefix "test" would not be answering this question.)

---

My local issue
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html#d1641324e49), select that you want to use regular expressions and use something like this for search/replacement pattern:

- Search pattern: `void test([A-Z]{1})(.*)\(`
- Replacement pattern: `void \L$1\E$2\(`

Note that it is a fairly crude solution, but it might be good enough in your case.

---

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. For example, "testInitBinder" is replaced by "LIEnitBinder".  Suggestions?

Comment: @LimaNightHawk Strange, it works for me (tested again in IntelliJ 15). What version of IntelliJ/what platform are you using?

Comment: Using 14.1.5. I'll probably upgrade next week to 15. Will post results. But, for clarity, these pairs are used in the Find/Replace at the top of the code window (Ctrl+R), correct? (And I did check "Regex" but nothing else.)

Comment: @LimaNightHawk Yep, see the attached GIF.

Comment: Wow. Nice Gif! I'm pretty sure my issue is somehow an environment issue. I tried the same find/repace in Notepad++ and it worked--so your solution is good! Thank you very much. Perhaps v15 will fix my issue.

Comment: Upgraded to Intellij 15. Works like a dream. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nowadays you can use \l to lower case a single character, so no need for the \E.